# Moving sprites in a vector

Tags: c++, sprite, sfml

I move sprites stored in a formationvector by holding the mousebutton. Problem is: Whenever i move the sprite onto another one, i move both sprites at the same time.

What i want: Moving the sprite1 over the other sprites2 without changing the position of sprite 2 or with other words:

-Testing in a loop if a sprite of a vector is clicked on

-If sprite is clicked on:

Move this sprite around while button is pressed but somehow stop this move while this movement in order to avoid moving more than this one sprite.

Here is my try so far:

```
while (App.pollEvent(Event))
    {
        // Window closed
        if (Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            return (-1);
        }

        if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
        {

            for (size_t k = 0; k < formation.size(); k++)
            {
                if (isMouseOver(formation[k], App) == true)
                {
                    Mouseposition = sf::Vector2f(sf::Mouse::getPosition(App));
                    Mouseposition.x = Mouseposition.x - formation[k].getLocalBounds().width / 2;
                    Mouseposition.y = Mouseposition.y - formation[k].getLocalBounds().height / 2;
                    formation[k].setPosition(sf::Vector2f(Mouseposition));
                    Formation_playernames.clear();
                    Formation_playerinformation.clear();
                    Formation_Playernames(Font, Formation_playernames, formation, playerlist);
                    Formation_Playerinformation(Font, Formation_playerinformation, formation, playerlist);
                }                                   
             }
         }
     }
```

The Formation-functions store the correct new positions of the sprites and their colors based on the positions into the formation vector
The problem is the for-loop, i could do it without but that would lead to a much longer code. How could i do it ?

Comment: If `Formation_playernames` is a vector, then I don't understand what your use of it on the next lines does.

Comment: I editet my post, it is a function that stores the new positions of the sprite into the formations vector. Before i delete the old one so that only the new position is stored and not both the old and the new

Comment: Ok I just noticed the p is lowercase in the variable and uppercase in the function. That's a very confusing style.

Comment: Yeah, maybe stupid design, but the functions are named with capital letters

Comment: Is this supposed to be like a click-and-drag functionality? i.e. You click on a sprite and you can drag it around until you release the mouse button?

Comment: Yeah right benjamin that is what i want to do, but i am not sure if this is the right way

Comment: So then, I take it, this section of code is executed each frame if the mouse button is pressed, correct?

Comment: Yes you are right, i edited the code and put more of it into my first post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of simply checking whether or not the mouse button is pressed, you should structure your code so you can check exactly when the button is pressed, and when it is released. You can then structure your code such that different presses of the button are distinguished from each other. semi-pseudocode follows

```
bool button_is_pressed = false;
Sprite* currently_selected_sprite = nullptr;

// main application loop
while (...)
{
    ...
    // other application logic
    ...

    if (!button_is_pressed)
    {
        if (CheckIfButtonIsPressed())
        {
            button_is_pressed = true;

            // Button was just pressed.
            // Select the appropriate sprite by checking
            // the mouse coordinates against the positions
            // of the sprites.
        }
        else
        {
            // Button not being pressed.
            // Likely no logic needed here.
        }
    }
    else // button_is_pressed == true
    {
        if (CheckIfButtonIsPressed())
        {
            // Button is being held down.
            // Implement dragging logic using the
            // pointer to the selected sprite.
        }
        else
        {
            button_is_pressed = false;
            // Button was just released.
            // Deselect the sprite.
            currently_selected_sprite = nullptr;
        }
    }    
}
```

Alternatively, you could handle mouse events, which will take care of much of this logic for you. http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Event.php

In a more English like pseudo code, this is what your function is doing:

```
if the mouse button is currently pressed
    move all the sprites which are under the mouse to be centered on the mouse cursor
else
    do nothing
```

This is what I'm suggesting

```
at the moment the mouse button is pressed down
    select the sprite which is under the mouse cursor
at the moment the mouse button is released
    deselect the selected sprite

if the mouse button is currently pressed, and a sprite is selected
    move the selected sprite to the position of the mouse cursor
```

Comment: This does not really answer my question as i'm already able to move drag my sprite. The only problem is my loop which leads to moving around more than one sprite if i drag on sprite over another

Comment: @jimbo999: Yes, it does answer your question. It avoids the problem of moving more than one sprite, because you only move around the sprite which you stored a pointer to. Did you try to implement it?

Comment: Is your if (CheckIfButtonPressed()) the same than  if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)) ? if not, i dont get what your checkbutton function is ;)

Comment: @jimbo999: Yes, I assume so. It's pseudocode. Check whatever button you want.

Comment: Thx works like a charme !!! One last question: Do i need to take care of any memory leaks with this pointer ?

Comment: @jimbo999: No. You are just using the pointer as a re-assignable/nullable reference. Not as a handle to dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: That is to say, this pointer does not own the object it points to (and using raw pointers for ownership should be avoided anyway).